# xlsxwriter creating files that are unreadable (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-2010, xlsxwriter

So I created a program that takes an image and replicates it onto an excel document by coloring the cells of the document the same as the pixels. Here is my code,

```
from PIL import Image
import xlsxwriter

image = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Image.xlsx')

image_sheet = image.add_worksheet()

with Image.open("11111.jpg") as px:
    cookie = px.load()
cookie2 = Image.open("11111.jpg")
image_pixels = 0
image_pixels_2 = 0
cookie_height = cookie2.height
cookie_width = cookie2.width
image_sheet.set_column(0, cookie_width, 2.14)

while image_pixels <= cookie_height - 1:
     print(image_pixels)
     while image_pixels_2 <= cookie_width - 1:
          rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % cookie[image_pixels_2, image_pixels]
          cell_format = image.add_format()
          cell_format.set_shrink()
          cell_format.set_bg_color(rgb)
          image_sheet.write(image_pixels, image_pixels_2, ' ', cell_format)
          image_pixels_2 += 1

     image_pixels += 1
     if image_pixels_2 >= cookie_width:
          image_pixels_2 = 0

image.close()
```

It produces the file but, when I open the excel file it says it is unreadable and removes all the formatting. I'm not sure why it is happening. The file is readable sometimes but other times it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has [a limit of 64,000 unique formats in a file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). XlsxWriter removes/replaces duplicate formats but it is possible that your program is exceeding the 64k format limit.

You can check by changing the your program like this to print out the number of unique formats used:

```py
unique = {}
while image_pixels <= cookie_height - 1:
     print(image_pixels)
     while image_pixels_2 <= cookie_width - 1:
          rgb = '#%02x%02x%02x' % cookie[image_pixels_2, image_pixels]
          unique[rgb] = 1
          cell_format = image.add_format()
          cell_format.set_shrink()
          cell_format.set_bg_color(rgb)
          image_sheet.write(image_pixels, image_pixels_2, ' ', cell_format)
          image_pixels_2 += 1

     image_pixels += 1
     if image_pixels_2 >= cookie_width:
          image_pixels_2 = 0

image.close()
print('Unique fomats = ', len(unique))
```